# Correct Join statement in Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I searched for the answer of my question, since am a beginner am not able to get those all, so asked my own,
I have two tables **SUBMENU** and **AUTHORIZATION** am tryin to put a join but not clear whether to put left or right or some other way, since am new to linq.

Here is what i have done so far,

```
var _lststage = 
    from sm in db.SUB_MENUs
    join a in db.AUTHORISATIONs 
        on sm.SUB_MENU_ID equals a.SUB_MENU_ID into joined_autho 
    from jA in joined_autho.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where sm.MENU_ID.Equals(ViewState["MenuId"]) &&
          jA.Roleid Equals ddlroleid.Selectedvalue
    select new
    {
         sm.SUB_MENU_ID,
         sm.SUB_MENU_NAME,
         jA.checkbox,
    };
```

I want to get all the submenus from the submenu table based on the menuid in view state, and,
I need to get the value for check box in Authorization table based on the role id and submenuid, and if there is no value for that role id in authorization table default false value should return.

Hope i explained my scenario well,
Possibilities of duplicate question...
Sorry if.

Answer (score 0):

Your query even will not compile. In your *where* condition second `Equals` should be method call:

```
 // instead of: jA.Roleid Equals ddlroleid.Selectedvalue
 jA.Roleid.Equals(ddlroleid.Selectedvalue)
```

Also you have unnecessary comma on last line of *select* statement:

```
 // instead of: jA.checkbox,
 jA.checkbox
```

---

Complete query should look like:

```
from sm in db.SUB_MENUs
join a in db.AUTHORISATIONs 
    on sm.SUB_MENU_ID equals a.SUB_MENU_ID into joined_autho 
from jA in joined_autho.DefaultIfEmpty()
where sm.MENU_ID.Equals(ViewState["MenuId"]) &&
      jA.Roleid.Equals(ddlroleid.Selectedvalue)
select new
{
     sm.SUB_MENU_ID,
     sm.SUB_MENU_NAME,
     jA.checkbox
};
```

I believe you have tagged your question appropriately, and this is Linq to SQL query.

Comment: Sorry i edited the last line and forget to correct..Thanks..but  can you suggest me what to do for my scenario??